# JQuery Inflector as fully featured as Rails' ActiveSupport Inflector?

Tags: jquery, string-utils

Is there a JQuery plugin with string utils on par with [ActiveSupport's Inflector](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html)?

I have found [this Prototype utils port](http://stilldesigning.com/dotstring/), but it's missing some of them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm a fan of inflection-js. It's stand alone, just extends the String prototype so you don't need any dependancies. It works really well.

http://code.google.com/p/inflection-js/

Answer (score 0):

Check out SugarJS, it has really good string support.

http://sugarjs.com/api/String